# How to create a fillable and savable pop-up form in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

How do I trigger a [fillable pop-up form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNHUK.png) when the user clicks on an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DRFd.png), on a Django web app that then winds up sorting the [following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKPD6.png) ?

I couldn't find a solution to that on other websites. Is this something that can be done solely with HTML, CSS, and JS, or do I have to use python to then save the data to the SQLite database?

If someone can suggest or hint at the steps that I need to follow to get this done I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

okay for the Popup you need some JS. For the Data of the Popup you have two options

- If the Data is static for this page you can add it in the Django template
- If its dynamic (it depends on user input at this page) you have to load it as a JSON and display it with JS (for example with [Django-Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Comment: Don't I need to pass the data from the html form to a python file ?

Comment: yes you can also do that with Django-Rest-Framework. Just create a Ajax request with an JSON encoded String